# How to update a row to add a character to a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL. I have a table, that has a column that I want to insert a character into.

For example, column `unique_reference` = `"1121464146-1-1R"`.  I would like to insert a `"-"` character before the `"R"`, so that it is `"1121464146-1-1-R"`.

I have the following incomplete SQL:

```
update powwowjournalentry
SET unique_reference = -- something?
where unique_reference LIKE '%R' and unique_reference NOT LIKE '%-R';
```

Comment: You can use Replace: `REPLACE (unique_reference, 'R', '-R');`

Comment: @Mani, that was simple.  Thank you, that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Replace:

```
update powwowjournalentry
SET unique_reference = REPLACE (unique_reference, 'R', '-R')
where unique_reference LIKE '%R' and unique_reference NOT LIKE '%-R';
```

Source: [postgresqltutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-replace/)